# How to edit Create Item In List action task after the task has been completed?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, task-list

I created a workflow which uses the Create Item In List action to assign custom tasks to users (such as fill in new employee details in a task form, then HR completes this task and 2nd task for giving equipment is triggered etc). Once this workflow is triggered users get an email notifying them they've been assigned tasks and giving them a link to the "Edit" version of the task form which allows them to complete the task straight away.

I have 2nd workflow running on the task list of Workflow 1 and when a task is complete it sends out email notifications to users. This email lists the outcome of the task and who completed it.

Currently there is no efficient option allowing a user assigning a task to edit the outcome of the task/information entered in the task form/ once they've mark the task as complete. Actually a user who has completed a task can go back and change the information in the task form and this will be updated, but the results email and the consequent tasks will have been triggered already. I haven't found any possible solution on the net suggesting how users can edit the information efficiently once they've marked a task as complete and the sequent task have been triggered.

**Could anybody suggest whether this is achievable?**

I guess I could add conditions saying trigger the subsequent tasks and resulting emails again if the complete button has been hit for 1+ times, but I haven't tried that yet because it I'm not sure how to avoid users getting lots of email to complete tasks which might have been updated or deleted already.